# Выгрузка файлов и запись их в фаил

Tags: php, html, radio

У меня есть 2 группы радио кнопок:

```html
        <form action="php.php" method="post">
            <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="answer1">
            <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="answer2">
            <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="answer3">
 
            <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="answer1">
            <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="answer2">
            <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="answer3">
            <input type="submit" name="save">
        </form>
```

Нужно, чтобы в фаил записывалось, какая кнопка нажата при клике на submit.

Comment: А в чем проблема? Вы сами что нибудь пробовали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php

        if(isset($_REQUEST['radio1'])) {

            $string = "radio1 ".$_REQUEST["radio1"];
            $file = fopen('text.txt', 'w');
            fwrite($file, $string);
            fclose($file);
        }


        if(isset($_REQUEST['radio2'])) {

            $string = "radio2 ".$_REQUEST["radio2"];
            $file = fopen('text.txt', 'w');
            fwrite($file, $string);
            fclose($file);
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> нужно, чтобы в фаил записывалось, какая кнопка нажата при тыке на сабмит

**send_to_file.php**

```
$radio1 = filter_var($_POST['radio1'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$radio2 = filter_var($_POST['radio2'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
// Pass filter
if(!$radio1 || !$radio2){
 // Если один из них не прошел фильтр то не запишет
  die('Send Wrong Radio Button');
}
$res = "radio1," . $radio1
       ."\nradio2," .$radio2 ."\n";
// Создает файл
$myfile = file_put_contents("data-file.txt", $res, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

- `FILE_APPEND` - добавит данные к существующим.
- `LOCK_EX` - блокирует от параллельных записей.

[Док про file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php)

[Док про filter_var](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-var.php)